# Create the query as a string and execute that in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create the query as a string and execute that in PostgreSQL 10.

As far as I know, I can use the EXECUTE command to execute my query from a defined string.

Unfortunately, I have got an error: **SQL Error [42601]:  ERROR: syntax error at or near "execute"**

Below is my code:

```
drop table if exists delinquent;
create table  delinquent 
(
    report_date date
    ,account_id text
)
;
INSERT INTO delinquent VALUES('2019-07-23', 'a1234');
INSERT INTO delinquent VALUES('2019-07-23', 'b5679');
--------------
drop table if exists output1;
create temp table  output1 
(
    report_date date
    ,account_id text
)
;
--------------
do $$
    declare table_name text := 'delinquent';
begin
    truncate table output1;
    insert into output1
    execute concat('select * from ',table_name);
end; $$;
select * from output1;
```

Anybody has an idea on what is wrong and what to do about it?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the complete INSERT statement as dynamic SQL. And to build dynamic SQL, using `format()` is highly recommended to properly deal with identifiers and literals:

```
do $$
declare 
  table_name text := 'delinquent';
  some_value text := 'a1234';
begin
  truncate table output1;
  execute format('insert into output1 select * from %I where some_column = %L',
                  table_name, some_value);
end; $$;

select * 
from output1;
```

Comment: Thanks for @a_horse_with_no_name your quick response.
But if I have multiple variables, how the code is?                                                                                                 
execute concat('select * from ',table_name, ' where column_name = ','a1234','''');




select * from delinquent where account_id = 'a1234';




Kindly please help me with this? Many thanks,

Comment: @Rosy: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) use `%L` for a literal

Comment: Thank you very much @a_horse_with_no_name